# Retrieve value from Dictionary<ulong, object> with partial Key

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dictionary of `accounts`

```
accounts<ulong, accounts>
```

In my code I am have a partial key.

**Question**: Is there a way to check if I can find the object with a partial key account.id using something like `startswith`?

Thanks

Comment: Without any other data structures only with O(n) effort which is probably not what you want for large dictionaries

Comment: What is does it mean by `partial key`? You mean partial number?

Comment: Yes a partial number.

Comment: I thought about that, regarding storage of IPv4 adresses. You can view them both as strings (wich is just a bad idea, I only mention it for completeness), 1 32-bit number. Or 4 8-bit numbers. But in order to do stuff like matching only the first or last segment, you would need to have them stored split up into 4 8-bit numbers ahead of time. If you knew at least wich part of the number (first or last) you are looking at, you might do some multiplication and >= checks. Could you give us some data what those numebrs represnet? And why you only got a partial number to work with?

Comment: The numbers represent ids for accounts. I am doing a look up from another system, and there is some error and i am getting only the first part of the id. I thought it would work as well if i can look up partial numbers with the last few digits truncated

Comment: You might want to use a [`Trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to do prefix look-ups.

Comment: Dictionary is not the right Structure for your case as it (by default) works with Whole Key (as Hash wont be the same). Other than what juharr has advised (Tree Search). Without knowing what the ulong (account ids) ranges are? How linear/densely/sparsely they are as in starts from 1000 and increase by one.. or some other random logic? But You can think & expand using Paged (Jagged Arrays) with your own Hash method. So basically... You need Multi-Page Array. [x, y, Page] - where each page is for a range of AccountIds (Say 1000 - 1999 on Pg1, 2000-2999 on Pg2 etc.) and Each Page itself is Sorted

Answer (score 2):

Although highly inefficient, the following should work:

```
IEnumerable<Account> FindByPartialId(Dictionary<ulong, Account> dictionary, ulong partialId)
{
    var partialIdAsString = partialId.ToString();
    var matchingKeys = dictionary.Keys.Where(k => k.ToString().StartsWith(partialIdAsString));
    var matchingValues = matchingKeys.Select(k => dictionary[k]);
    return matchingValues;
}
```

Probably you may want to keep a copy of the dictionary where the keys are directly strings and search on it instead:

```
var accountsByStringKey = accounts.Keys.ToDictionary(k => k.ToString(), k => accounts[k]);
```

so you can do `.Where(k => k.StartsWith...` instead of`.Where(k => k.ToString().StartsWith...`